# Change transform rotation from X to Z axis

Tags: unity-game-engine, rotation, quaternions

I have a transform which is being rotated around the X axis. But while transferring this rotation to another transform, i want it to do the exact same rotation. But then around the Z axis.

However, this rotation is not a "rotation" it is just a transform which rotation gets edited from the outside. So i have to rotate the original transform to match the 2nd transform, but take the rotation into account.

Axis in below images: RED = X, GREEN = Y, BLUE = Z

Rotation original:

[image][image]

Rotation it should have after:

[image][image]

What would be the correct way to go about this frame by frame?

Thanks in advance,

Smiley

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can give you an answer that solves the general problem of changing the rotation from one axis to another.

Each transform object has a `transform.localRotation` property that represents the orientation of the transform, relative to the parent's orientation. If the transform has no parent, than this orientation is relative to World Space.

`Quaternion` is the data type used to represent rotations, and it has a useful method called [ToAngleAxis](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Quaternion.ToAngleAxis.html).

```
float angle;
Vector3 axis;
transform.localRotation.ToAngleAxis(out angle, out axis);
```

Will set the variables `angle` and `axis` to the angle and axis of `localRotation`. The `out` part means that you're passing in a variable meant to be set by the function, rather than to be used as input.

In this case, the `angle` variable is the part you want to actually use. If you use [Quaternion.AngleAxis](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Quaternion.AngleAxis.html), providing this `angle` value and your desired axis, you'll get a new rotation that will match your desired parameters.

For example: To change any rotation of `transform1` to a Z-axis rotation on `transform2`, you would use

```
float angle;
float axis;
transform1.localRotation.ToAngleAxis(out angle, out axis);
transform2.localRotation = Quaternion.AngleAxis(angle, Vector3.forward);
```

Hope this helps